# Gray square effect when pressing a HTML element on IPhone

Tags: html, css, iphone, ionic-framework

On the following code I have the `Ionic 4` component: `Range`.

JSFiddle source:
https://jsfiddle.net/681539w0/

Direct result:
https://jsfiddle.net/681539w0/embedded/result/

Inline demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>index-ionic.html</title>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@latest/dist/ionic.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <ion-range mode="ios" min="0" max="120" pin="true" value="60"></ion-range>

</body>
</html>
```

In desktop browsers it is fine. Also, on Android browsers it is fine.

But on `IPhone` (real device) browser (for example: `Chrome`), when you press the handler, there is one gray square that shows up as you can see on the following image:

[image]

I want to prevent that because it doesn't look good.

In the other hand, if you go to this demo:

https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/content/component-preview-app/docs-www/?ionic:mode=ios&ionic:statusbarPadding=true#/range

and press the handlers you don't get that gray square.

Any idea on how to prevent this?

Thanks!

Comment: who do you check it in real iphon or in computer that demo iphone... I ask it because if you use computer maybe it because the mouse event and when you try by finger touch it does not happened

Comment: I checked on a real IPhone. The image above is just an screenshot on it.

Comment: I don't if this cause the issue but their `html` tag has different attributes. Their: `<html lang="en" mode="ios" class="ios">` compare to your: `<html class="plt-desktop md" mode="md">`

Comment: I tried with that with no success: `<html lang="en" mode="ios" class="ios">`

Answer (score 1):

Set the `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` CSS property to `transparent`, like so:

```
html {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```